# Two sides of a triangle and the angle in between them are known. How to find the 3rd side?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Two sides of a triangle are $3$ units and  $\sqrt {41}$ units. The angle between them is $135^\circ$. What is the length of $3$rd side ?

Comment: Make a picture of the problem please

Comment: Do you mean that two sides are $3$ and $\sqrt {41}$? Then use cosine law.

Answer (score 3):

One answer is you can use [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)